# Python regex doesn't work on string

Tags: python, html

I have an HTML file that I process using lxml and BeautifulSoup (convert from HTML to text). Somehow, the ill-formed HTML below makes it into the text and I'd like to remove it. I tried matching something like "<.+>" in the text string, but it doesn't work. The string I want to remove is this:

```
string = """ .trb_m_b:befoe{ctent:'Hide comments'}.trb_c_so{padding-top:10px;min-height:500px}||<div class="trb_c_so" data-role=c_container><div class="s_comments" data-sitename="ffff" data-content-id="jksjkj7878787" data-type=promo-comment data-publisher="ronctt"></div></div>"""
```

The exact code I tried on it is:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'<.+>')
if (pattern.search(string)):
    print ("Found")
```

However, that regex doesn't match the string, although it should.

Why would that be?

Thanks.

EDIT. It looks like the problem is not with the regular expressions, but with something very bizarre. I have this string in a list, it's the last item. When I loop through it the first time, for some reason, the program never hits it. The second time, however, it does. I don't understand the reason for it.

EDIT2. It turns out the problem was that I was trying to remove elements in a loop (if they matched the regex), which is not permitted. I rewrote the code to use a list comprehension, and now it works fine.

Comment: beautiful soup will close any unclosed open tags for you ...

Comment: I don't want to close the tags, just want to remove the offending text.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is this:

```
import re
data = re.findall("\<(.*?)\>", string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not a complete HTML tag, if you really want to match the string that you give,you can use this：

`re.findall("\.trb_m_b.*?></div></div>", string)`

Comment: Right, I realize that it's not a complete tag. However, the regex I gave should match it, shouldn't it? Since there is an HTML tag inside the string. I wanted a more general expression so that I could match whatever ill-formed HTML that could appear, not just this particular string.